# Can't run a react docker image in a container when mapping directories with --volume in windows

Tags: reactjs, docker, windows-10, volumes

I am new to docker and what I am trying to do is to run a react image mapping a directory to current host directory, so that is possible to make changes in the files on the host, that would be automatically reflected in the image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

images in docker :

[images in docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnLvY.png)

I am trying to run a docker react image in Windows 10, using this command:

docker run -d -p 5000:3000 --name container1 -v %cd%:/app docker-react-master-dev

The behaviour expected is to create a container named container1 that runs react and sets up a webpage in
port 3000 of the container localhost, 5000 of the host. Instead, it creates the container but in a few seconds the status of the container is Exited(127), and the logs are :

[container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Suk.png)

When I am not trying to add a volume, it works fine (it creates a container that doesn't stop and it listens to port 5000 on the host).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you somehow overwritting the start script so it no longer exists

Comment: I'd recommend removing the `-v` option, so that you're using the code built into your image.  If you want to work directly on code on your host system, using an isolation system like Docker seems to work against your goals; I'd [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download) directly on your host system and just use that.